# Pass by reference within File Find function in perl

Tags: perl

I have read a few post similar to this, but they dont quite have the answer I want. Basically, I am struggling to do pass by reference with this File::find function. The original code is huge. So I take out pieces of the code.

Note that

```
$node,$ref_p, $ref_alphaSUM ,$ref_rank, $ref_sorted_alpha, $output_file
```

are all variables or references of global variables. I need to recursively traverse through the directories and apply the &eachFile subroutine to each file, which will update my variables stated above. The "&whichFiles" subroutine just sorts the filenames.

*First problem:* Since not all files in the directories contains the string **nfcapd**, i have added the line **if(/^nfcapd./)**  to check the if the name of the file contains this string. But since I am also passing those variables above to eachFile, the "$_" cannot be used now.

Thus, **I believe  This is why I kept getting the following error:(please correct me if I am wrong):**

```
Use of uninitialized value $File::Find::name in pattern match (m//) at
    ./pvalues.pl line 178, <PRE> line 65184 (#1)
```

Line 178 is the line where **if(/^nfcapd./)** appears in the code below. 
This leads to 2nd problem: How to do pass by reference within find function and at the same time preserving a variable for the name of file such that I can still check if the "&eachFile"  is being applied to the correct files?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find ({wanted => \&eachFile($node,$ref_p, $ref_alphaSUM ,$ref_rank, $ref_sorted_alpha, $output_file), preprocess => \&whichFiles},$flow_data_path);


sub eachFile    {
    my ($node , $ref_p, $ref_alphaSUM ,$ref_rank, $ref_sorted_alpha , $output_file) = @_;
       if(/^nfcapd\./){
             #do something
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass variables to your wanted sub, you need a closure:

```
sub eachFile {
    my ($node , $ref_p, $ref_alphaSUM ,$ref_rank, $ref_sorted_alpha , $output_file) = @_;

    if(/^nfcapd\./){
        #do something
    }
}

my $wanted = sub { eachFile($node,$ref_p, $ref_alphaSUM ,$ref_rank, $ref_sorted_alpha, $output_file) };

find({wanted => $wanted, ...});
```